# xlwings: How to write values to a combo box from python UDF

Tags: xlwings

I am new to using xlwings in excel VBA programming.

I need to send values from a list in python UDF to a combo box in excel sheet.

I found an example at [Example 2](https://programtalk.com/python-examples-amp/xlwings.Book.caller/) but i am unable to get it to work in my code.

Is there a simple example to write values from a list to combox, then read back a value and send to python UDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you are trying to do - here's how I populate a combobox control (not ActiveX) on a spreadsheet:

```
def fill_name_cb():
    cb = ct.WS_MAIN.shapes("cbNames").api.ControlFormat
    cb.RemoveAllItems()
    cb.AddItem("Select Client")
    cb.AddItem("Add New Client")
    cb.AddItem("Update List")
    for name in ct.CLIENT_NAMES:
        cb.AddItem(name)
    cb.ListIndex = 1
```

The variable `ct.CLIENT_NAMES` is a simple list, like `["Name 1","Name 2", "etc"]`

Then, in VBA, I have this macro that runs this using `RunPython`:

```
Sub fillComboBox()
    RunPython ("import helpers; helpers.fill_name_cb()")
End Sub
```

`helpers` is the name of the Python module. So this doesn't exactly use UDFs, but I think this does what you want (?). If not, let's keep at it!

Now, if I could only figure out how to get the actual name of the selected item, I'd be in great shape - but that seems to escape me.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this!