# xlwings: fill the combobox of a user form from a panda dataframe

Tags: python, excel, combobox, userform, xlwings

I have a pandas dataframe containing the records of an SQL query.
I would like to use xlwings to insert the data of this dataframe into the combobox of a user form.

I have something like that:

```
cb = xw.Book.caller().sheets.active.shapes("ufm_PortfolioCompo.cbb_DALI_ptf_id").api.ControlFormat
cb.RemoveAllItems()
for id in df_dali_ptf_id:
    cb.AddItem(id)
    cb.ListIndex = 1
```

This is the error message I get:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 1134, in __call__
    return self._wrap(xl=self.xl.Item(key))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 63, in __call__
    v = self.__method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in Item
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, "The item with the specified name wasn't found.", None, 0, -2147024809), None)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks very much in advance!

I looked at xlwings documentation.
I also try to mimic an example coming from this post;
[xlwings-how-to-write-values-to-a-combo-box-from-python-udf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154656/xlwings-how-to-write-values-to-a-combo-box-from-python-udf)

Comment: What does the pandas dataframe look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can just write the Dataframe to a sheet and reference it with your combobox;

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": ["foo1", "foo2", "foo3", "foo4", "foo5"],
})

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book()
    ws = wb.sheets[0]

    ### Write the Dataframe to the sheet
    ws["A1"].options(index=False, header=False, expand="table").value = data

    ### Create Combobox
    cb = ws.api.Shapes.AddFormControl(2, 96, 0.6, 48, 16.2)
    ### Reference the dataframe data
    cb.OLEFormat.Object.ListFillRange = "$A$1:$A$5"

    wb.save('foo_out.xlsx')
```

Sheet:-
[image: Example Output]

Comment: Thanks very much for your help @moken. The thing is that I would like to use the combo box that is on a user form (a Forms object according to MS terminology). The idea is that user presses a button > it opens the user form > on this user form there is a combo box that is filled with the Python script (thanks to an SQL query stored into a Pandas DF). Do you think it is possible to reach the combo box of the user form? Not one that is on the sheet. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: @mandela Accessing a combo box on a form is perhaps difficult. Do not know for sure, not used Xlwings with Forms and never seen any specific code doing that sort of thing. Certainly creating a macro to populate the combo box should work, i.e. when button is clicked or form loaded etc it uses VBA to populate from the dataframe values. You can use Xlwings to create and add macros to a workbook thus manipulating what the macro contains based on the dataframe values e.g. what range is used from a sheet or create the array or '.AddItem' lines to add the values.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer @moken. Much appreciated!